# How to do a link_to with method post inside a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two nested forms:

```
<%= form_for(@post, remote: true, html: { class: "postform"})  do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= form_for(Tag.new) do |ftag| %>
        ...
    end
end
```

Now, i want to submit the innerform "ftag" to a create a new "Tag" using ajax, 
give that back to my view to populate the view with new tags (Tags and post has a HABTM-relationship)

My question is, how to do this "the-rails-way"?
If i just can get the post and create a new tag to work, i can manage the callbacks et c myself i hope.

I was thinking of doing this, though i dont think that is the correct way of doing it:
Using jquery, 
Add a listner to a button inside of the form, and posting to my controller outside of rails, and pushing the response back to my view.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: you can not put form inside form

Comment: You can't do nested forms.

Comment: @rubyist yes well... how can i do what i want, even if i dont nest them? I can add the input fields without an additional form_for, but should i do the POST as i suggested, with jquery/ajax outside of rails?

Comment: you just send your input field value via ajax and after successfully return from controller just replace your view as you want...........onblur of your input or just put a button ........and clicking on same send ajax to controller

Comment: Why not create a new tags in the Model or Controller. Just accept all the tags and then iterate over them and create them if they don't exist currently?

Comment: @engineersmnky becouse i want to be able to create several tags at once. I solved it using my own ajax code, its not very nice. but it works like a charm :)

Comment: glad you got it fixed although I am not sure why you can't create multiple tags at once using something like `params[:post][:tags].split(" ").each{|tag| Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag)}`